# getting mx:CheckBox values from inside mx:Repeater

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

I have an an array of objects that I use as the datasource for my repeater.

```
<mx:Repeater id="categoryRepeater" dataProvider="{this.allCategories}">
<mx:HBox>
<mx:Spacer width="20"/>
<mx:CheckBox id="categoryCheckBox" label="{categoryRepeater.currentItem.question}"/>
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Repeater>
```

I would like to be able to tell which of the checkboxes in the list have been checked, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I know I can add a function when it's clicked, but I don't know how to tell which checkbox called the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`currentIndex`](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/design/assets/flex3/langref/mx/core/Repeater.html#currentIndex) property.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of an example?  Here's what I'm trying: <mx:CheckBox id="categoryCheckBox" click="myFunction(categoryRepeater.currentItem)" .... />   However it appears that the function is never called

Comment: sorry, that should say categoryRepeater.currentIndex

Comment: The link to the Flex 3 documentation I posted originally, has an example at the bottom. Just replace currentTarget.getRepeaterItem() by currentTarget.currentIndex and try.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is a very old post, but I had run into the same issue and the currentIndex was not a sufficient answer for me. What I found to work better was to create a function on click:

```
<mx:Repeater id="rp" dataProvider="{dp}">  
<s:CheckBox height="100%" width="100%" label="{String(rp.currentItem)}"  
click="showAlert(event);"/>
</mx:Repeater>
```

and the showAlert function looks something like this:

```
private function showAlert(evt:MouseEvent):void {
  var curBox:CheckBox = evt.currentTarget as CheckBox;
  var str:String = curBox.content.toString();
  if(curBox.selected)
    Alert.show(str + " clicked");
}
```

This way you can deal with the event as a CheckBox inside of your ActionScript code and find values such as whether or not it has been selected etc.